# Using Vector Tile Maps Offline in a Hybrid App (ArcGIS API for JavaScript)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, vector-tiles, vector-layer

I will create a hybrid map by using ArcGIS API for Javascript. I want to use my own hosted vector tile basemap as offline. What do you advise?

Are there any ways to use ESRI Vector Tile Package (.vtpk) file as offline without serving on portal or Arcgisonline?

Comment: or can I read directly local ".mbtiles" files by using javascript?

Comment: No, the JSAPI doesn't support either vtpk nor mbtiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js, there are ability use .tpk files.
[This is example](http://esri.github.io/offline-editor-js/samples/tpk-layer.html), but it work only with ArcGis js api v3.15+

[offline-editor-js with 4.x version](https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js/issues/506)